# Dynamic polymorphic has_many associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a polymorphic, has_many through association between `Service` and `context` through `ServiceUsage`. The `context` models (currently `Scenario` and `Mapping`) include a `ServiceConsumer` mixin that declares the following associations:

```
has_many :service_usages, as: :context, dependent: :destroy
has_many :services, through: :service_usages, dependent: :destroy
```

`ServiceUsage`, the join table, defines the following associations:

```
belongs_to :service, inverse_of: :service_usages
belongs_to :context, inverse_of: :service_usages, polymorphic: true
```

`Service` currently has:

```
has_many :service_usages, inverse_of: :service
```

With the current setup, there is no way to get from `service` to the to the associated objects (either Scenario or Mapping).

One solution is to add explicit associations to `Service` for each `Scenario` and `Mapping` as follows:

```
has_many :scenarios, through: :service_usages, source: :subject, source_type: Scenario
```

I think there is a better way to do this to avoid explicitly defining the associations on `Service`.

I've been thinking of something along these lines:

```
module ServiceConsumer
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    has_many :service_usages, as: :context, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :services, through: :service_usages, dependent: :destroy

    Service.class_eval <<-EOF
      has_many #{self.to_s.underscore.pluralize.to_sym}, through:     :service_usages,
                                                         source:      :context,
                                                         source_type: ::#{self}
    EOF
  end
end
```

The idea is that when a model includes the `ServiceConsumer` concern, it defines on `Service` a `has_many` association for that particular model.

This sounds great in principal but I haven't been successful in getting it to work yet.

Any thoughts/comments/suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Do you think this is too obscure? Would it be better just to explicitly define the `has_many` associations on `Service` for each polymorphic associated model?

Thanks!

Comment: in my experience there is no need in overkilling DRY principe. While it is one line of code copy-pasted 2-3 times diving in metaprogramming is not beneficial at all, leading to some unexpected result, headache on plain spot. You go with that if expect 10, 20, etc models where this can be included.

Answer (score 1):

`has_many #{self.to_s.underscore.pluralize.to_sym}` this line in your concern is fundamentally wrong. Like if `Scenario` includes it, it'll translate to `has_many :scenario` inside `Scenario` model, which makes no sense.

On the other hand, you must maintain a balance between dry and meta programming. Unnecessary Metaprogram may overkill the benefit.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
Tag.class_eval %Q"
  has_many :#{model_name.plural}, through: : service_usages, source: :context, source_type: #{model_name.name}
"
```

and I don't think metaprogramming is an overkill in this case.